# Magento 2 can't log in to admin

Tags: magento-2.1, admin

I have a live and testing servers. I have cloned my live website to the development stack and have some problem when trying to access it.

I have edited the local machine `hosts` file and mapped the DNS, however when trying to access the website it was redirecting to the live website. I managed to fix this by editing 4 rows in my `core_config_data` table for my development site:

```
web/unsecure/base_url       -> http://dev.mydomain.com

web/secure/base_url         -> http://dev.mydomain.com

web/unsecure/base_link_url  -> http://dev.mydomain.com

web/secure/base_link_url    -> http://dev.mydomain.com
```

However, if I navigate to the `dev.mydomain/admin` and try to log in, it gives me error that the username or password is incorrect or the account has been temporary disabled.

I had similar problem with Magento 1 and fixed it by either commenting out these lines in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php`:

```
$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
    // 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    // 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    // 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

Or running a query in MySQL client:

```
 DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path = "web/cookie/cookie_domain";
 DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "web/secure/base%";
 DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "web/unsecure/base%";
```

Anyone know how to solve the problem with **Magento ver 2.1.8**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be user issue where the user might be disabled, or it might be cookie issue.

Unlock the user first and try to login

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock
```

Try to set cookie domain 
web/cookie/cookie_domain = ".mydomain.com"

Also try to save session on Database or under /tmp 
how to locate sessions: 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/sessions.html

Do a full reindex of Magento.

Try to create another user using

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create
```

Do cache clean and cache flush.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: The `web/cookie/cookie_domain` should be set to my dev site or live site? Should it be like ".dev.mydomain.com`?

Comment: if you have url of the local website http://dev.domain.com then the cookie domain should be .domain.com
even if you have the url of the local website http://domain.com the  cookie domain should be .domain.com

Comment: created new user and re-indexed, it worked! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can check

> admin_user

table in your db. There is a

> is active

column. Check it.

Comment: The account is set to 1 so it is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new User through SSH:

> php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='user1'
> --admin-password='admin123' --admin-email='admin@admin.com' --admin-firstname='Admin' --admin-lastname='Admin'